# What is a cairngorm "Comparator"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Can anyone explain this in easy to understand terms?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Adobe's 5 part series](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/cairngorm_pt1.html) - whether it is easy to understand depends on the individual users perspective!

Also [this post](http://nyls.blogspot.com/2006/11/flex-cairngormfiltering-data-with.html) describes the "comparator" much like a filter.